# Select distinct values from two columns in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, group-by, distinct, min

I have two columns

```
tab1
col1   col2
a       1
a       2
b       3
b       6
c       4
d       5
```

I need distinct values from both columns at once like:

```
result
col1     col2
a         1
b         3
c         4
d         5
```

```
select distinct col1, col2 from tab1 #is not giving such results.
```

Is that possible in sqlite?

Comment: How would you determine which value is the correct one?

Comment: @Fildor It does not matter. I just need unique pairs.

Comment: You just said unique pairs. In your example, where a-2, b-6 went, why not present in result manually made (they are unique)?

Comment: _" If the simple SELECT is a SELECT DISTINCT, then duplicate rows are removed from the set of result rows before it is returned. For the purposes of detecting duplicate rows, two NULL values are considered to be equal. The usual rules apply for selecting a collation sequence to compare text values. "_ This does not apply here, since you do not have duplicate rows. (Source: https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#distinct)

Answer (score 2):

From the sample data you posted I see that the easiest way is to `group by col1` and get the minimum of `col2`:

```
select col1, min(col2)
from tab1
group by col1
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your expected result (which is not distinct rows, but other thing).
What you want formally is not clear, below will select minimum values of column 2 for each column 1.

```
select col1, min (col2) from tab1 group by col1
```

If you want to select first of each, let it be known to you, that order of values is not defined in SQL unless e.g. you add numeric id and sort by it.

*NOTE: noted forpas answered before me, so please mark his answer as accepted in case you consider our answers the same.*